If boiling happens at the surface of a liquid, why do bubbles appear at the bottom?
So apparently boiling is just accelerated evaporation, which happens when molecules at the surface of the liquid gain enough kinetic energy to jump out of the liquid state and become a gas.
However, when boiling a liquid in a kettle, I see large bubbles rise up from the bottom of the kettle, like so: 
I assume these are not the bubbles from dissolved air, but rather the water turning into gas and rising up. How can the water turn into gas beneath the surface, if evaporation/boiling only happens at the surface?

Who told you boiling only happens on the surface? Evaporation happens on the surface; boiling takes place in all the parts of the liquid. As all the parts have to reach $373K$ to enter into the boiling state.

You are right that boiling and “normal” vapor pressure that leads to slow evaporation are essentially the same process with one small caveat. Namely, the temperature of the substance does not change with added input of energy during boiling until the liquid is all boiled off unlike in evaporation. This is because the equilibrium vapor pressure of the liquid becomes the same as the ambient atmosphere, and the input of further energy to the liquid will not be sufficient to change that ambient atmosphere in everyday conditions (aka in the atmosphere). All the energy thus is used in converting the liquid into vapor which then diffuses away from the liquid until you have boiled the all the liquid away.
You were also right to presume those bubbles are not from dissolved air. Henry’s law predicts the amount of a gas dissolved in a liquid at a given temperature and pressure, and these would be tiny amounts of gas for air’s components and water under normal conditions.
To explain what is properly going on, the source of the heat is at the bottom of the pot, which is where the water will start to boil because its molecules acquire a significant amount of energy very rapidly there. The water molecules that are sufficiently hot to break their hydrogen bonding network like vapors will then rise through the liquid as bubbles due to a difference in density until they either cool back down (the ambient water is not yet hot enough to fully boil) or they will start to really escape the pot by boiling off. The tricky part here is that there is a temperature gradient throughout the water in the pot until the temperature has equilibrated and you have achieved a steady boil. The example you give is very extreme where the molecules by the burner are rapidly vaporizing and blasting through the liquid in the form of large bubbles. While it is true we can best mathematically understand the boiling process by looking at the equilibrium liquid-vapor interface at the surface (which is why textbooks refer to vapor pressure “above the surface”), the first water molecules to acquire enough energy from the heating element will be those at the the bottom as you rightly predicted.

In general evaporation is the change from the liquid phase to the vapour phase at the interface between liquid and and vapour occurs at all temperatures whereas boiling is the change of phase in the bulk of the liquid and occurs at the boiling point.
If you observe the boiling process in a liquid you will note that a lot of the vapour bubbles expand very rapidly.  This is due to the local temperature of the liquid being above the boiling point and so the water is "superheated".
The vapour bubbles need to form on a "nucleation site" which could be solid particles in the liquid, and surface imperfections, eg scratches, in the containing vessel and once formed the conersion from liquid to vapour is very rapid.
This effect can be reduced by adding anti-bumping granules, sharp edges, small, irregularly shaped pieces of (porous) material, into the vessel.
Video demonstration of boiling induced in superheated water..


So apparently boiling is just accelerated evaporation,
which happens when molecules at the surface of the liquid
gain enough kinetic energy to jump out
of the liquid state and become a gas.

No, boiling is not exactly the same as evaporation.
You are right that evaporation only occurs
at the surface, where molecules which happen to
have a high enough speed can leave the liquid.
But boiling occurs throughout the bulk of the liquid.
When the temperature has reached the boiling point,
then liquid can turn into gas because at that
temperature the vapor pressure is high enough
to overcome the air pressure exerted on the liquid.

If you closely study the formation of boiling bubbles in the very bottom of the pot you will notice that most of the bubble origination sites are fixed in place and generate repeated bubbles from the same spot. This is because of tiny scratches and pits in the pot surface which have extremely tiny amounts of air stuck in them which furnish nucleation sites for the vaporization process.
This is true when the pot first begins to boil. with progressive boiling, the nucleation sites eventually run out of air and whatever boiling begins on the bottom happens from sites that do not repeat.
You can poison those sites by putting detergent into the water. This will dislodge most of the air from the cracks, especially if you allow the detergent-spiked water to cool down in the pot, which allows the detergent to penetrate to the bottom of the cracks, and then heating it up again.
